# Spring Boot - Process finished with exit code 0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I've looked at various links to stackoverflow and other sites to see if anyone else faced a similar issue. I found a few but none of them had solved my problem. Tried to fiddle around with some of the answers but still nothing worked;

I've got a Spring Boot Application, and when booted up, it shows `Process finished with exit code 0`. I've added the necessary dependencies to allow the application to know it's a Web App but still it does not work. I've also tried cleaning + building from Maven as well as refreshing it.

Here's my Setup

pom.xml

[image]

console output
[image]

Comment: Spring Boot returns an exit code of 0 when it finishes and exits successfully. Does this occur as soon as you start it or after some time or after doing something?

Comment: An exit code of `0` traditionally means "all good". As in, the process finished execution successfully. Though I suspect you want your Spring Boot application to run for a long time, and for some reason it's exiting prematurely? If so, please provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @GeorgeR - Yes this happens immediatly after. I've attached the console output screenshot above showcasing the error occurs shortly after.

Comment: Could you remove the dependency spring-boot-starter-tomcat and try again ?

Comment: Can you please share main class as well?

Comment: Also please share full pom.xml file

Comment: I created a spring boot project with the same configuration of pom.xml no problem, you can share application.properties and the main class please! and whitch EDI you have Eclipse , VS Code or IntelliJ-Idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue. For some reason, Spring Boot 3.0.0 paired with Java 17 was causing the "silent error" of exit code 0. I've changed my Spring Boot to 2.7.6, java version to 11, and SDK to 11. Everything worked fine.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.6</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>


<java.version>11</java.version>
```

Comment: That still doesn't explain how to fix it with Spring Boot 3. Do you have a solution without reverting Spring Boot back to version 2?

Answer (score 1):

For `Spring Boot 3` and `Java 17` it seems like adding the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

did the trick to keep the web server alive. Make sure to reload `maven` in your IDE (e.g. `IntelliJ`) and then rebuilding the entire project.

Without this dependency, the following will be printed by `Spring Boot` before exiting the process:

```
2023-05-16T14:39:35.249+02:00  INFO 31392 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-05-16T14:39:35.253+02:00  INFO 31392 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-05-16T14:39:35.260+02:00  INFO 31392 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

The full example `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-postgresql-docker</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-postgresql-docker</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Keep the web server alive -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependency to the specific database implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```